# Syntax error but its just two lines of code

Tags: python

Here's what I typed

```
a = 50
print(a)
```

And here's what I got

```
>>> & "C:/Users/Niranjan S Pednekar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "c:/Users/Niranjan S Pednekar/Desktop/Python practise/index.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & "C:/Users/Niranjan S Pednekar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "c:/Users/Niranjan S Pednekar/Desktop/Python practise/index.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Earlier I had conda not activated popping up in the terminal, but reinstalling anaconda solved it.

I even downgraded the python(3.9.xxx) because the latest one also gave me same errors

Right now if I run the file its gives me the syntax error.

However, if I run it step by step, it works

Comment: That might be the contents of your file, but it's *not* what you typed at the interpreter prompt, which is the text immediately following the `>>>`, starting with `&`.

Comment: It looks vaguely like you misinterpreted a shell command as something to type in the Python interpreter, then replacing the `$` with a `&` instead of omitting the `$` altogether.